# Instagram API - get date of the first post of any user in instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

All I want to do is to get the date of the very first post of any instagram user. I tried this tool [Apigee](https://apigee.com/console/instagram?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22get_users_follows%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22get%22%7D) but I am not sure if this would really help me get the date. Is this possible? I really need direction. TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to get a user's first post, you have to make API call until there is no more pagination and get the last post in that response.

You can call this API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Look for response with no pagination.

```
if(!json_response.pagination || !json_response.pagination.next_url){

    first_post_date = json_response.data[json_response.data.length-1].created_time;
}
```

If the user has a lot of posts, then you can use a smarter way to make API call by using `max_timestamp` param in API call and search with a time between now and July 2010(start of Instagram) and check for response, if there is response data[] and pagination, try `max_timestamp` = earlier date; if there is no response data[] try later date. Kind of like bubble sort until you find a response with data[] and no paganation.next_url, that will have the first post

`created_time` is in epoch format, convert it to the desired format.

Comment: but I think data[0] means the most recent... and the api returns only 20 media per request... if the user has more than a 1000 media posted I don't think this is possible.

Comment: oh, that right, i read the question wrong, will update answer